# Average of one column based on distinct values and group by of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the SQL, I am using. But the average is not averaging on the distinct job numbers, it is using them all.

I would like to get the average work time and total number of unique jobs, by customer. The average time has to be based on unique job numbers only.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(DISTINCT JOB_NO) AS JOB_COUNT, AVG(WORK_TIME) AS WT 
FROM CYCLE_TIME 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Charles, I used your first query and tested it with one customer. I get 5 jobs for the customer with the following WT values. `28.95, 24.72, 2.56, 15.14, 8.94`. That's an average of `16.06`.

If I use the following query and only group by customer, the average (WT) ends up as 22.39. I'm not sure what's happening there.

```
 SELECT CUSTOMER, JOB_NO, AVG(WORK_TIME) AS WT 
 FROM CYCLE_TIME 
 WHERE CUSTOMER='customer_a'
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your own calculation for `AVG` based on `SUM()/COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER,
    COUNT(DISTINCT JOB_NO) AS JOB_COUNT,
    SUM(WORK_TIME)/COUNT(DISTINCT JOB_NO) AS WT 
FROM CYCLE_TIME 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include job number in the group By.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, JOB_NO, AVG(WORK_TIME) AS WT 
FROM CYCLE_TIME 
GROUP BY JOB_NO, CUSTOMER
```

if you also want to know how many job_nos each customer has, that needs to be in a separate subquery

```
SELECT ct.CUSTOMER, 
   (Select Count (Distinct JOB_NO) 
    From CYCLE_TIME  
    where CUSTOMER = ct.Customer) JOB_COUNT,
   JOB_NO, AVG(WORK_TIME) AS WT 
FROM CYCLE_TIME ct
GROUP BY JOB_NO, ct.CUSTOMER
```

Remember the average of averages is not necessarily the overall average.  One Job may have many more records than another.

Run this query and you will see the difference:

```
 SELECT ct.CUSTOMER, Count(*) numRecords,
   (Select Count (Distinct JOB_NO) 
    From CYCLE_TIME  
    where CUSTOMER = ct.Customer) JOB_COUNT,
   JOB_NO, AVG(WORK_TIME) AS WT 
FROM CYCLE_TIME ct
GROUP BY JOB_NO, ct.CUSTOMER
```

If you're overall average is 22.39, then there are probably many more records for the jobs with high job averages than there are for those with low job averages

Comment: charles, I tried the first query and detailed the results in my original post. I'm not sure if that's how we're supposed to respond to posts or not